# processing the contents of an XML email attachment as a String using MimeBodyPart

Tags: java, xml, email

I am trying to process an email attachment (.xml) using MimeBodyPart.

```
attachment = part.getContent();
```

This returns the Java object of type StreamSource (and not a String)

How can I convert this into a String. I am using BufferedReader and StringBuilder to reconstruct the String from InputStream, but the reconstructed String is incomplete

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
InputStream inputStr = attachment.getInputStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStr));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
   }
```

If I process the email atttachment as a .txt instead of a .xml the MimeBodyPart.getContent() returns the attachment as a complete String. I want the same functionality when the email attachment is a .xml

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the character encoding of the attachment? Perhaps you need to take that into account when constructing your reader/stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The character encoding for the XML attachment is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "UTF-8" encoding as a parameter to your InputStreamReader.

Comment: did not return the expected String

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the sender sent the full XML document? What is the content-type that the sender specify in the headers?

Comment: Yes. The sender is me ..my email is monitored and the attachment is picked up and processed using JMS.. That's  how I am trying both .txt and .xml file extensions..The only header in the XML is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: No, I meant the email header.

Comment: I checked and it is application/xml; name=<Filename>.xml   for contentType = part.getContentType()